# SQL return in fix format while matching content with from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates, match

I have two tables:

Table TIMELINE (with fixed content)

```
Value |
-------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Table PROD_ENTRY (with entry from time to time)

```
entry_1                | entry_2    |   entry_3   |
---------------------------------------------------
2017/09/25  01:25:00       1              aaa
2017/09/25  01:26:00       1              bbb
2017/09/25  03:32:00       2              ccc
2017/09/25  04:15:00       3              ddd
2017/09/25  05:05:00       5              eee
2017/09/26  13:25:00       7              fff
```

I would like to return always in Table A format while matching Table B entry into return

```
new_value |  entry_time            | entry_2  | entry_3  |
----------------------------------------------------------
    1       2017/09/25 01:26:00        1        bbb
    2       2017/09/25 03:32:00        2        ccc
    3       2017/09/25 04:15:00        3        ddd
    4       null                      null      null
    5       2017/09/25 05:05:00        5        eee
    6       null                      null      null
    7       null                      null      null
```

Following is my code:

```
SELECT 
coalesce(T1.entry_2, T2.Value) as timecode , 
T1.*
FROM 
(SELECT tt.*                                           ----
FROM prod_entry tt                                        |
INNER JOIN                                                |
(SELECT entry_2, MAX(entry_time) AS MaxDateTime           |- to remove duplicated entry_2
FROM prod_entry                                           |
GROUP BY entry_2) newtt                                   |
ON tt.entry_2 = groupedtt.entry_2                         |
AND tt.entry_time = newtt.MaxDateTime) T1              ----
FULL OUTER JOIN TimeLine T2
 on T1.entry_3 = T2.Value
WHERE (T1.entry_3 is null or T2.Value is null)
OR
T1.entry_time > '2017-09-25 00:00:00' AND T1.entry_time < '2017-09-25     23:59:00' AND T1.entry_1 = '1'
order by timecode
```

However I am getting below, where the new_value '7' is missing

```
new_value |  entry_1               | entry_2  | entry_3  |
----------------------------------------------------------
    1       2017/09/25 01:26:00        1        bbb
    2       2017/09/25 03:32:00        2        ccc
    3       2017/09/25 04:15:00        3        ddd
    4       null                      null      null
    5       2017/09/25 05:05:00        5        eee
    6       null                      null      null
```

May I know which part I do wrongly at the remove duplicate?

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Hi Tim, I am running this query on SSRS 2008

Comment: Left justified SQL... So hard to read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server, I think the easiest thing to do is just to use `ROW_NUMBER` with a basic left join between the two tables.  Then, subquery that and retain only the most recent row for each value in the timelime table.

```
SELECT
    new_value, entry_time, entry_2, entry_3
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t1.Value AS new_value,
        t2.entry_1 AS entry_time,
        t2.entry_2,
        t2.entry_3,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Value ORDER BY t2.entry_1 DESC) rn
    FROM TIMELINE t1
    LEFT JOIN PROD_ENTRY t2
        ON t1.Value = t2.entry_2
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

I would use `LEFT JOIN` with `GROUP BY`

```
 SELECT tt.value AS new_value, 
        tt.entry_1 AS entry_time, 
        tt.entry_2, 
        pe.entry_3
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT t.value, MAX(p.entry_1) AS entry_1, p.entry_2
   FROM TIMELINE t
   LEFT JOIN PROD_ENTRY p ON p.entry_2 = t.value
   GROUP BY t.value, p.entry_2
 ) tt
 LEFT JOIN PROD_ENTRY pe  ON pe.entry_2 = tt.value and pe.entry_1 = tt.entry_1
```